# Find area of a magnified polygon

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I have a highly irregular polygon made out of polylines for which I KNOW the area A1, the perimeter P1. I can offset this polygon (magnify it) by offsetting every site by a given distance d. Is there any way I can evaluate with precision the new area A2? Please do not mind the grey  lines, only the red ones count[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "by offsetting every site by a given distance d"? This is *not* the same as magnifying a region, which is done by *multiplying* the distance of each point from some given central point by a given ratio $r$. We might be able to help if you are more specific.

Comment: this is actually an offset command on AutoCAD I imagine what it effectively does is magnify the polygon like you said. In any case regardless of what the computer does, I am magnifying the polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know AutoCAD. But if you are magnifying the polygon in the usual way (multiplying the distance of each point from some given central point by a given ratio $r$) then the area of the new polygon is
$$A_2 = A_1 \cdot r^2$$

Comment: How does that ratio relate to the distance d?

Comment: I cannot say since I have no idea how $d$ is used in your magnification. Perhaps you should be more clear in *how* you do your magnification.

Comment: a parallel line is drawn to each side of the polygon. This parallel line is offset distance d from the original line. the offset line is extended until it meets another offset line from another side. I apologize for the confusion and my less-than-clear explanations. Please let me know if this is clear enough.

Comment: each polygon side is offset a distance d

Comment: I see now. I cannot imagine that there is a general formula for such as case, since the area is "expanded" at convex corners and is "truncated" at concave corners. I would expect that you would need to find the vertices of the new polygon and calculate its area from scratch, using the usual methods.

Comment: yeah ive just been reading up online actually, you are right this is more of a finite elements problem especially since its actually a volume problem. Thank you for your help anyhow. I will accept your answer.